# stop links having an underline on a space?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way in html and css to stop links having an underline where there is a space? Say I want a small icon with a space and then text to all be a link but have no link between them, is it possible?

I don't want to have to have the icon jammed right next to the text :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add a margin to your image - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sCS4y/)

```
img {
    margin-right: 15px
}
```

Comment: Nice, never thought of that!

Comment: Legend! Exactly the kind of thing I wanted :D

Comment: Very good idea. Another proof that we are learning a lot when dealing with "simple" questions. +1

Comment: If you want the space itself to be clickable, you should use `padding-right` instead of `margin-right`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mH6vG/

HTML:

```
<a><i class="icon-file"></i> <span>My link text</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
a > span {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Zoltan Toth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1499781/zoltan-toth)'s solution is very nice and simple. +1 for that. But let me throw in my $0.02 as well. If you don't want to have an extra image tag for an icon in your link, you can also use this:

**HTML**

```
<a href="">Some lorem ipsum text</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    vertical-align: top;
}

a:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    background: transparent url(http://lorempixel.com/20/20) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/xQAzy/

Answer (score 0):

You can add the icon and the text as two separate links pointing to the same location.

Comment: Hmm is that really the only way? CSS has no way to not style spaces on links?

Answer (score 0):

You can either have two separate links (one for the icon and one for the link), or you can set `text-decoration: none;` to both.